# Outlook 2010 VBA Save Message as MSG Will Not Work as Script

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to get a script inside an Outlook rule to automatically save e-mail messages to a file server when they are received from a certain user/domain.

I found the following VBA Script on this site and it works if I manually run it, but it will not work inside my Outlook rule that says to use a script.

```
Sub SaveMessageAsMsg()
  Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
  Dim objItem As Object
  Dim sPath As String
  Dim dtDate As Date
  Dim sName As String
  Dim enviro As String

    enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))
   For Each objItem In ActiveExplorer.Selection
   If objItem.MessageClass = "IPM.Note" Then
    Set oMail = objItem

  sName = oMail.Subject
  ReplaceCharsForFileName sName, "-"

  dtDate = oMail.ReceivedTime
  sName = sName & ".msg"

    sPath = enviro & "\Desktop\Allied E-File\"
  Debug.Print sPath & sName
  oMail.SaveAs sPath & sName, olMSG

  End If
  Next

End Sub

Private Sub ReplaceCharsForFileName(sName As String, _
  sChr As String _
)
  sName = Replace(sName, "'", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "*", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "/", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "\", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, ":", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "?", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, Chr(34), sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "<", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, ">", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "|", sChr)
End Sub
```

Comment: If you are making a rule based on this you need to pass a mailitem as a parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but it will not work inside my Outlook rule that says to use a script

The argument must be type **`MailItem`** for the subroutine to be available in the Rules Wizard in Outlook to work

Example

```
Public Sub SaveMessageAsMsg(oMail As Outlook.MailItem)

     'Your code here

End Sub
```

**Edit**

Tested on <kbd>**Outlook 2010**</kbd>

```
Option Explicit
Sub SaveMessageAsMsg(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim dtDate As Date
    Dim sName As String
    Dim Enviro As String

    Enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))

    sName = Item.Subject
    ReplaceCharsForFileName sName, "-"

    dtDate = Item.ReceivedTime
    sName = sName & ".msg"

    sPath = Enviro & "\Desktop\Allied E-File\"
        Debug.Print sPath & sName
    Item.SaveAs sPath & sName, olMsg
End Sub

Private Sub ReplaceCharsForFileName(sName As String, _
  sChr As String _
)
  sName = Replace(sName, "'", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "*", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "/", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "\", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, ":", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "?", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, Chr(34), sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "<", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, ">", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "|", sChr)
End Sub
```

See here [how to create rule](http://support.sherweb.com/Faqs/Show/how-to-create-rules-in-outlook-2010-exchange-2010)

Comment: Thank you Omar for the example as I am a new at writing VBA scripts.  I added the oMail As Outlook.MailItem and saved my project.  I sent another test e-mail, on which I can manually run the script and it works; but I am not having any success with the automation portion.  I am going to reach out to Microsoft as this seems to be an Outlook rule issue. @Matt

Comment: Your updated answer worked!  Thank you so much!! I also created my rule following the how to create rule (only difference is that took me to File-->Info-->Manage Rules & Alerts and I was originally using the button on my ribbon bar--not going to argue with it as it is now working!)