# Save Created Emails as .msg

Tags: vba, outlook

I have code I use every day. It converts a tab to pdf, creating emails with created pdf attached, and takes subject name from a range.

Example, if that range contains four delivery references, the code creates four emails with same pdf attached.

I want to save these created emails to a Windows folder as .msg.

I tried SaveAs method.

```
Sub Oval2_Click()
Dim IsCreated As Boolean
Dim i As Long
Dim PdfFile As String, Title As String
Dim OutlApp As Object
Dim sPath As String
Dim sName As String
Dim rng As Range, c As Range

Set rng = Range("B10:B14")
For Each c In rng.Cells
    If c <> "" Then '----------------------------------
        Title = c

        PdfFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        i = InStrRev(PdfFile, ".")
        If i > 1 Then PdfFile = Left(PdfFile, i - 1)
            PdfFile = PdfFile & "_" & "Information" & ".pdf"

            With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Information")
                .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PdfFile, _
                  Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                  IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
            End With

            On Error Resume Next
            Set OutlApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
            If Err Then
                Set OutlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
                IsCreated = True
            End If
            OutlApp.Visible = True
            On Error GoTo 0

            With OutlApp.CreateItem(0)

                .Subject = Title
                .To = ""
                .CC = ""
                .Attachments.Add PdfFile

                On Error Resume Next
                .Display

                sPath = "Any folder"
                sPath = sPath & m.Subject
                sPath = sPath & ".msg"

                OutlApp.SaveAs sPath

                Application.Visible = True

                On Error GoTo 0

            End With

            'Kill PdfFile
            'If IsCreated Then OutlApp.Quit

            Set OutlApp = Nothing
        End If '---------------------------------
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Try to use `.SaveAs sPath` instead `OutlApp.SaveAs sPath`

Comment: hi, i tried. unfortunately still no luck. just does not save anything

Comment: Comment  `On Error Resume Next` before `.Display` and watch what kind of error occurs.

Comment: Use .SaveAs sPath as suggested and define a valid path instead of sPath = "Any Folder" see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.saveas

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31599812/4539709

Comment: Hello, thanks for replies. I am not sure but just think sPath is defined correctly and set to dekstop. When I comment  `On Error Resume Next` , code creates first email, and returns "Object  does not support this property or method" error.

Comment: Hi, i already tried to work on stackoverflow.com/a/31599812/4539709  I had no luck

Answer (score 0):

VBA coding success increases with use of `Option Explicit` and limiting use of `On Error Resume Next` to the rare appropriate situations.

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration

Sub Oval2_Click()

Dim IsCreated As Boolean
Dim i As Long

Dim pdfFile As String
Dim Title As String

Dim OutlApp As Object

Dim sPath As String
Dim sName As String

Dim rng As Range
Dim c As Range

' Rare appropriate use of On Error Resume Next
On Error Resume Next
Set OutlApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If Err Then
    Set OutlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    IsCreated = True
End If
OutlApp.Visible = True
' restore normal error handling 
On Error GoTo 0

pdfFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
Debug.Print pdfFile

i = InStrRev(pdfFile, ".")
If i > 1 Then
    pdfFile = Left(pdfFile, i - 1)
    Debug.Print pdfFile
End If

pdfFile = pdfFile & "_" & "Information" & ".pdf"
Debug.Print pdfFile

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Information")
    .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, fileName:=pdfFile, _
      Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
      IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
End With

Set rng = Range("B10:B14")

For Each c In rng.Cells

    If c <> "" Then '----------------------------------

        Title = c

        With OutlApp.CreateItem(0)

            .Subject = Title
            .To = ""
            .CC = ""
            .Attachments.Add pdfFile

            ' Inappropriate "On Error Resume Next" removed

            .Display

            sPath = "Any folder"
            'sPath = "C:\Users\username\Test\"

            Debug.Print sPath

            If Right(sPath, 1) <> "\" Then
                sPath = sPath & "\"
                Debug.Print sPath
            End If

            ' error would be bypassed due to poor error handling
            ' would have been caught by Option Explicit
            'sPath = sPath & m.Subject
            sPath = sPath & .Subject
            Debug.Print sPath

            sPath = sPath & ".msg"
            Debug.Print sPath

            ' error would be bypassed due to poor error handling
            'OutlApp.SaveAs sPath
            .SaveAs sPath

        End With

    End If '---------------------------------

Next c

'Kill pdfFile
'If IsCreated Then OutlApp.Quit

Set OutlApp = Nothing

Debug.Print "Done."

End Sub
```